# Creating calendar with array and loops using C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to create an application that tells you the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, etc;) when a date from 2016 is entered (January 1, September 3rd, etc;) Input is the date, output is the day of the week for that date. It has to be created with loops such as a for loop and if statements. I cannot use library functions. Starting date is January 1st, 2016, a Friday. This is what I have so far, i'm pretty lost:

```
    public enum Days : byte { Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday };
    public enum Months : byte { January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December };
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int numDays = 7;
            const int numMonths = 12;
            Months month = Months.Janurary;
            int monthCounter = 1;
            int[] daysinMonth = new int[numMonths] { 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
            int[] daysofWeek = new int[numDays] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
            Days dayOfWeek = Days.Sunday;
            dayOfWeek = Days.Friday;
            foreach (month in Months )
            {
```

My brief is:

> Using only the tools we have covered to date, find the weekday name of a specific date in 2016, working from Friday January 1 2016, using nested loops and comparisons.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? What kind of output are you trying to create? Mocking it up and adding to the question will make this clearer.

Comment: Are trying to implement the c# DayOfWeek?

Comment: `new DateTime(2016, 1, 16).DayOfWeek` will give you the same result so..

Comment: If you are trying to do this from scratch, e.g. for an exercise, then I guess you'll have to pick a base date where you know what day that was, and count the number of days between that date and your input, at least mod 7. You can probably simplify that by making it the 1st January or 31st December of some year, then count 365 or 366 %7 days for each year different (beware of leap years and the 400-year leap year rule), then the days in the months to the target date, then the number of days.

Comment: I'm not trying to use the library functions. I have to do it manually with loops. I edited the post. Hopefully that provides a bit more clarity.

Comment: This question seems too broad as it currently stands, in fact you haven't actually asked a question. What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: Do you *have* to do it with loops? There's an [algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determination_of_the_day_of_the_week#Zeller%E2%80%99s_algorithm).

Comment: You only entered January 1 but your program should identify it as January 1, 2016. How does it do that? What are the criteria for picking the year? As it would affect the day of week.

Comment: This is verbatim what my assigment says: "Using only the tools we have covered to date, find the weekday name of a specific date in 2016, working from Friday January 1 2016, using nested loops and comparisons." Sorry if it's too vague: I guess what I'm trying to figure out is how I would make a for loop for this/what other loops I would use.

Comment: I don't see why you'd need nested loops, unless you're expected to loop through the days in the month too, changing the current selected day? But that's silly. You don't really need comparisons either, or indeed any loop. OK, so if you're restricted to 2016 that's much easier: given a month and a day of the month, work out what day number that is in the year e.g. by summing the number of days in the months before this one, or just looking that sum up in an array, and adding the day of the month. Then take this modulo 7 and correct so that 1 = Friday.

Comment: Or when you say "when a date is entered like January 1" are you expecting the user to enter "January 1" ? You'll need to split that string on spaces (probably trimming it first) then match the first part (case insensitively?) against your enum's .name(), and then Int32.Parse the second part.

Comment: If you're willing/able to edit the question, including a tip about what "tools we have covered to date" would be helpful.  Also, general life tip, you don't have to use _every_ tool for _every_ job.

Comment: What kind of class is it? Algorithms, C# programming course, computer science class of some sort?

Comment: It's an intro to c# class basically.

Comment: Well, you'll need to establish at least one day-to-date mapping. Consider creating one routine to establish leap years or not (remember 2100 is not a leap year). Then another to decide, given a date, what day-number of the year it is (i.e., Feb 3 is day #34). That will involve two int arrays of length 12 each (number of days in each months, leap years & not). Then pick a zero year (say 1900) and figure out what what Jan 1 was that year (also not a leap year). Count out how many days till the year you are interested in, .. And I've run out of space

Comment: Do you know, that SO is not a code-writing service? As it is _your_ assigment, I think it is _your_ responsability to do the job. Your code just defining some variables and do nothing. Have you watch any video or lecture of this "C# class"? Do you have an idea how you should solve this?

Comment: Please don't write the code for me. I just asked for help with how I would go about doing this, mainly just with how I could write a forreach loop for it. I have been working for 7 hours now and I've hit a wall. Is there a video or lecture you could link that explains this? My textbook doesn't seem to cover this clearly and i havent been able to find anything that does. Most of the calendars ive seen use library functions and im trying not to per the instructions. How do I tie the day to the date with the variables given?

Comment: @Jackie: since you didn't want code, I preface my answer with a full explanation of how to get to a solution.  By the way, you don't really want a `foreach` loop, you really want a simple `for` loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want code, I'll give you some explanation and just a little code.  Then, once that's all done, there's full code at the bottom of this that will give you all you need for an arbitrary date.

However you are interested only in the year 2016.  As a result, if you do want todo is calculate the day of the week for a specific year, all you need (from the full code) is the class declaration, and two functions:

- GetDayNumberFromDate
- GetDayOfWeekFromDate

### Explanation and Just a Little Code

I would do all this in a static class.  You don't need an `instance` of anything, just a few functions/methods.

In that class I would declare and intialize three private variables:

- An array of 12 integers, each of represents the number of days in each month.  Remember that array indexing starts at zero, so you need to subtract one form a month number (1-12) to get the array index (0-11).  I also suggest you put a comment noting that 2016 was a leap year and that's why February has 29 days
- A private `const` integer (perhaps named `YearOfInterest`) that is set to 2016.  It represents a symbolic alias for the number 2016.  Consts make your code easier to maintain (consider if you teacher changes his mind and says "no, do it for 2014" and you used 2016 in six or eight places in your code - if you had a `const`, you'd only need to change one of those places.
- Something that represents the fact that January 1, 2016 is a Friday.  I would use the System.DayOfWeek enum (yeah, it's library code, but anything you do will be pretty much a character-by-character repeat of that).  If you wanted to, you could use your `YearOfInterest` const int and do something like (which will allow things to work if your teacher changes his mind about the year)

That would be a very simple declaration like the following:

```
 private readonly static DayOfWeek Jan1DayOfWeek = new DateTime (YearOfInterest, 1, 1).DayOfWeek;
```

I think it's a lot cleaner than just saying:

```
private readonly static DayOfWeek Jan1DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Friday;
```

Remember that enums start numbering (by default) at zero, so Sunday is 0 and Saturday is 6.

With that done, I'd create two functions:

- One that calculates the `Day Number` for a date (i.e., the number of days that have passed in the year until that date (the day number for Jan 1 is `1`, and for Feb. 3 is `34`).
- One that calls your `Day Number` function (i.e., getting an integer) and returns a day of the week.

The first function (let's call it `GetDayNumberFromDate`) takes a two integer date (month and day) does three things:

- It checks your pre-conditions.  Since both those number are user-entered, and users make mistakes you need to make sure than both numbers are equal to or greater than 1, that the month number is equal to or less than 12, an that the day number is equal to or less than the number of days in the month (which you conveniently know - it's in your array (remember to subtract one when you index into that array).  If any of these preconditions are not met, throw an exception.  This is important.  If someone enters a wrong number, you will likely index out of your array (which will throw an exception, but without the information about why it happened).  Checking pre-conditions is always good
- It loops over your "days in a month" array, from the beginning of the array until the month before the month entered (minus one) summing the number of days.  If someone enters April 4th, you want to add the number of days in January (31), February (29) and March (31).  That will get you to the beginning of the month (well, the last day of the previous month).
- It adds in the day of the month entered - that gets you to the current day.

Since you wanted coaching on the for loop, that loop would end up looking like this:

```
int dayCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < month - 1; ++i) {
    dayCount += daysPerMonth[i];
}
```

At the end of the loop, `dayCount` would tell you the number of days from the start of the year until the end of the month before the entered date.  When you add in the day of the month that was entered, presto, you get the `day number`.

Finally, the last function (call it `GetDayOfWeekFromDate`) also takes those same two integers (month number and day of month number).  It calls `GetDayNumberFromDate` to get the day number for the entered date, subtracts one (since calculations starting from 0 are much easier than from 1) and adds in the integer equivalent of that `Jan1DayOfWeek` we declared at the beginning (`(int) Jan1DayOfWeek`).

With that in hand, I'd take that number and do a "modulus 7" operation (`thatNumber % 7`).  A modulus is the result of calculating the remainder of an integer division.  That will get you a number between 0 and 6.  If you cast that number back into a `DayOfWeek` it will get you a day of the week between Sunday and Saturday.  Call `ToString` on that result, and you have your result.

Do not be surprised if the result is off (particularly if it's off by one).  Getting this right the first time is tricky.  That's where debugging comes in.

By the way I would **not** try to parse a date like "January 1".  You'd really need to take care of abbreviations (Jan, Feb, ...), and you'd upset folks who can't spell "February".  Just use month and day integers.

One thing you will notice in all this is that there are no nested loops.  There's no need for that, and nested loops can be expensive.  This code loops over the number of months that have passed (i.e., less than 12 times).  If you were to loop over the months and the days in the month, you would be loop 12 times 30-ish times (i.e., about 366 times).  12 is a smaller number

### The full code follows:

I don't know what you have learned, so this is mostly in pretty basic circa 2005 C#.

First a static class with a few basic "constants":

```
static class FigureDate {
    private static readonly int[] _leapYearDaysPerMonth = new int[] { 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
    private static readonly int[] _normalYearDaysPerMonth = new int[] { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

    private const int YearZero = 1900;
    //Sunday is zero in DayOfWeek
    private readonly static DayOfWeek _day0 = new DateTime(YearZero, 1, 1).DayOfWeek;
}
```

*(By the way, DayOfWeek is a `enum` defined in the System namespace, so you get it for free.  Sunday is 0)*

I'll be adding more stuff to that class - everything (i.e., all the functions below) goes in there.

First, is a particular year a leap year (which is never trivial to figure out):

```
public static bool IsLeapYear (int year) {
    if (year % 400 == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if (year % 100 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    //otherwise
    return (year % 4) == 0;
}
```

Then I figure how may leap years have passed since "day 0" (luckily, 1900 is not a leap year, so the likelihood of an off-by-one error is reduced):

```
public static int NumLeapYearsToStartOfYear(int year) {
    if (year < YearZero) {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Only Years from {YearZero} onwards can be evaluated");
    }
    //do it brute force
    int count = 0;
    for (var y = YearZero; y <= year; ++y) {
        if (IsLeapYear(y)) {
            ++count;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Armed with that, I can figure out how many days from "day 0" till the start of the year of interest:

```
 public static int DaysToStartOfYear(int year) {
     return (year - YearZero) * 365 + NumLeapYearsToStartOfYear(year);
 }
```

Now, switching gears, figure out what "day number" the interesting day is (remember, Feb 3 is Day number 34).

```
public static int GetDayNumberFromDate (int year, int month, int day) {
    int[] daysPerMonth = IsLeapYear(year) ? _leapYearDaysPerMonth : _normalYearDaysPerMonth;
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Month number ({month}) is invalid");
    }
    if (day < 1 || day > daysPerMonth[month - 1]) {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Day/Month combination invalid for month:{month}, day:{day}");
    }
    int dayCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < month - 1; ++i) {
        dayCount += daysPerMonth[i];
    }
    return dayCount + day;
}
```

and finally put it all together.  As you might imagine, there's an off by one issue in this code.  I use the "Day Number" of the date, and it is in the 1...N range, and we really want it to be 0...N-1.  So, I subtract 1.

```
public static DayOfWeek GetDayOfWeekFromDate (int year, int month, int day) {
    int totalDays = DaysToStartOfYear(year) + GetDayNumberFromDate(year, month, day) - 1 + (int)_day0;
    return (DayOfWeek)(totalDays % 7);
}
```

if you call that function and then call `ToString` on the result, it *should* work.  I've only very lightly tested it.

***Please*** don't just submit this as your work.  Take it apart, see if you can do it better.  If you know how to write unit tests, write a test for each function (which I would normally do, but not tonight).  Figure out shy I showed you the functions I showed you in the order I showed you them.  Why do I check arguments where I do and not everywhere?  Why do I use `readonly` where I use it and `const` for `YearZero`?  Some of the code is very brute force - see if you can do better (it's a lot easier to get better code once you have good enough code).

At the end, you should be able to explain every line of code.

Comment: Sorry, the comment about only looking only at 2016 was one of the N more comments, and I never looked at it.  I have no idea why you'd need nested loops.  If you use 2016 as a start date, beware that I didn't test this with a YearZero that is a leap year

Answer (score 1):

Now that I understand your assignment is entirely focused on 2016 as a year, that your brief requires you to use nested loops, and the code you've provided, I recommend this:

1) Define targetMonth and targetDate (e.g. September, 3)
2) Ensure daysOfWeek starts as Friday
3) Use this pseudocode:

```
foreach mMonth in Months
    for dayOfM = 1 to daysinMonth[month] (inclusive)
        if month == targetMonth AND dayOfM == targetDate
            print dayOfWeek
            return
        else
            dayOfWeek = (dayOfWeek + 1) % 7
```

Useful functions:

- `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Months))` will return all of the values from `Months` as an array.
- `.OfType<Months>()` (include `using System.Linq` namespace) - you can use this to convert the `Array` returned by `Enum.GetValues()` into strongly typed `Months` objects.
- You can cast `dayOfWeek` to an integer using `(int)dayofWeek` and back by using `(Days)5` (or whatever integer value you have).
- Modulus `%` will return the remainder of your calculation. 1 % 7 = 1, 2 % 7 = 2, ..., 7 % 7 == 0 - this will allow you to loop through the days of the week.

This was the solution I came up with in C# and worked back to pseudocode so as not to provide you with a copy/pastable answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could take is to calculate the total number of days from the start of the year to the specified date, find the remainder after dividing that number by `7` (total days in a week), and then add the numeric value for the first day of the year.

First, we'd add the total number of days in each month before the month they entered. To do this, we first need to figure out which month they entered and then convert that to an integer that we can use as an index into our `daysInEachMonth` array.

We can first get the enum for the string they entered by using the `Enum.Parse` method (which takes in the type of `Enum` to use for parsing (`Month` in our case), and a string value like "January", and returns the `enum Month` value). Then we can cast this value to an `int`. By default, Enums start with a value of `0` and increment by `1`, so `Januray` is `0` and `December` is `11`.

```
int monthNumber = (int) Enum.Parse(typeof(Month), month, true);
```

Using this value, we can loop through each month before this one and add the total number of days up to this month:

```
for (int i = 0; i < monthNumber; i++)
{
    daysFromStartOfYear += daysInEachMonth[i];
}
```

Next we'd add the day of the month they entered and subtract 1 (we need to subtract one since we're dealing with array indexes and `enum` values that both start at `0`):

```
daysFromStartOfYear += dayDate - 1;
```

Now we need to adjust our number by adding the numeric value of the first day of the year (where `Sunday` is `0` and `Saturday` is `6`). If this doesn't make sense, just remember that if they entered `January 1`, then our `daysFromStartOfYear` value would be `0`, but we know the first day of the year is `Friday` (which has an `int` value of `5`). So we know we need to add `5` to the result in order to account for the first day not starting at `0` (Sunday).

```
Day firstDayOfYear = Day.Friday;
daysFromStartOfYear += (int) firstDayOfYear;
```

Now all that's left to do is divide this number by `7` (the number of days in the year), get the remainder, and convert that number to a value in the `Day` enum. If this doesn't make sense, just remember that every `Tuesday` in a month has a date that is some multiple of `7` plus the value of the first `Tuesday` of the month. By getting the remainder of the value after dividing it by `7`, we end up with a number between `0` and `6`, which will map to our `Day` enum.

To get the remainder of a number divided by another, we can use the modulus operator `%`:

```
int remainder = daysFromStartOfYear % numDaysInWeek;
```

When we get this number, we can then cast it to our enum to get the value:

```
Day answer = (Day) remainder;
```

Hopefully this is enough to get you started. Give it a try and come back if you get stuck on something specific, or feel free to ask questions in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wish to display Day of Week, can do like this:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2016, 1, 16);
Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("dddd"));  // outputs Friday
```